Как правильно понять грамматику предложения и расставить знаки? (Филип Сидни. Пыл искренней любви)
Это Филип Сидни (1554-1586) — придворный, государственный деятель, воин, поэт и покровитель ученых и поэтов. В истории английской литературы он остался трижды новатором — в области поэзии, прозы и теории литературы.
             Чужие книги я листал за томом том:
             Быть может, я мечтал, какой-нибудь поэт,
             Мне песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
             Спаленный солнцем мозг, подскажет путь... Но нет!

Мне кажется, что не все запятые верны, к тому же грамматика предложения трудно понимается на слух. Как более удачно расставить знаки? Или лучше бы внести изменение в текст? (Перевод В. Рогова)
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Вроде бы мне стала ясна ПРИЧИНА сомнений) И всё совсем НЕ ТАК, как я думала.
Но вопрос пока оставляю для обсуждения. То есть как эту причину устранить, чтобы читателю текст был понятен сразу и однозначно?
В этом-то уж нет сомнений: предложение имеет ДВА варианта прочтения, а верен только один. Так какой же?  Назовите варианты, отгадайте загадку))
20.07.2024 КОНКУРС ПРОДОЛЖАЕТСЯ. Второй ответ Риммы порадовал меня выбором тире и сравнением текста с оригиналом, это шаги в нужном направлении, но не окончательное решение, как я его сейчас вижу.
Но я не уверена в в том, правильно ли вижу. Поэтому надеюсь на ваше участие и помощь.
24.07.2024  Конкурс скоро ЗАКАНЧИВАЕТСЯ, а канонического ответа у меня, к сожалению, нет.  Еще раз повторю вопросы. Правилен или нет авторский вариант? Если есть погрешности в грамматике, стилистике, пунктуации, то какие? Можно ли их исправить? А то времени уже мало) Можно очень коротко: три ответа на эти три вопроса. Обратите особое внимание на дополнение МНЕ.
Ответ несложный, можно просто догадаться. Да или нет на первые два вопроса. Если есть неточности, то надо выбрать одну из трех названных (грамматика, стилистика, пунктуация).  Хотя бы это назовите) Просто попробуйте для интереса. Я только предположила, что не все запятые верны, но не исключено, что там нет ошибки.
ПОЛНЫЙ ТЕКСТ
Пыл искренней любви я мнил излить стихом,
Чтоб милую развлечь изображеньем бед -
Пускай прочтет, поймет и сжалится потом,
И милость явит мне за жалостью вослед.

Чужие книги я листал за томом том:
Быть может, я мечтал, какой-нибудь поэт,
Мне песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
Спаленный солнцем мозг, подскажет путь... Но нет!

Мой слог, увы, хромал, от Выдумки далек,
Над Выдумкою бич учения навис,
Постылы были мне сплетенья чуждых строк,
И в муках родовых перо я тщетно грыз,
Не зная, где слова, что вправду хороши...
"Глупец! - был Музы глас. - Глянь в сердце и
                                      пиши."


Под предложением надо понимать четверостишье?

Практически да, кроме последнего "Но нет!". А что, есть сомнения? // Стих красивый, выразительный. Для XVI века весьма художественный и необычный, чуть ли не разговорный стиль. Английское Возрождение!  // Предложение сложное, бессоюзная связь, деепричастная конструкция.

Мне кажется, Sharon, что правильно "Из Филипа Сидни..."

Запятая после "поет", действительно, не нужна. Как вы верно отметили, здесь местоимение дополнение. После "том" скорее многоточие. Тире тоже подойдет. В целом согласен с вашим ответом.

*поэт................

@Серж  Можете дать четкий ответ?  Правилен или нет авторский вариант? Если есть погрешности в грамматике, стилистике, пунктуации, то какие? Можно ли их исправить?  А то времени уже мало)  Можно очень коротко,   Пока у меня нет такого ответа.  Обратие особое внимание на дополнение МНЕ.

Ну я же написал в комментарии.

Ну значит, это не тот ответ, который мне нужен.  Я изменила свое  начальное мнение, поэтому и задала конкурсную тему.  Первый из моих вопросов особенно важен: правильно или нет?  И если неправильно, то почему?

Я бы написала так:
Чужие книги я листал за томом том —
Быть может, я мечтал: какой-нибудь поэт
Мне, песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
Спаленный солнцем мозг, подскажет путь... Но нет!

Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Неплохой вариант,  вполне на уровне.  Деепричастный оборот на письме вроде бы  неплохо смотрится (я имела в виду именно эту пропущенную запятую).  Но  оборот сложно читается,  его границы не подчеркнуты,  Фраза распадается на отдельные речевые отрезки, так что неясно, что к чему. Да еще это сочетание: "мозг, подскажет путь", оно провоцирует на неправильное управление. Но не знаю, можно ли что сделать.

Дополнительный ответ
Я обратила внимание вот на это сочетание из сонета:
my sun-burn'd brain = мой обожженный солнцем мозг.
Возможно, переводчик специально изменил "мой" на "мне" — во избежание такого неправильного прочтения: ...какой-нибудь поэт, мой... (мой поэт).
А может быть, стоило оставить?
Просто нужна пауза побольше после слова "поэт". Этого можно добиться с помощью двух тире, оформив как вставку. Тогда и диссонанс от управления, кажущегося неправильным, будет меньшим.
Само же предложение я бы все-таки не стала делить — дозволительно, думаю, поставить точку с запятой.
Талантливейший аристократ XVI века, "переходный" английский язык...
Нужно ли осовременивать? Осмелюсь...
Чужие книги я листал за томом том;
Быть может, я мечтал: какой-нибудь поэт —
Мой песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
Спаленный солнцем мозг, — подскажет путь... Но нет!
✦ Еще одно дополнение (после комментария)
Да, конечно, можно и "мне" оставить...
Но тут так много запятых, которые затрудняют понимание, и в любом случае "получается далеко" (и от определения "мой", и от дополнения "мне").
Никто ведь на запрещал обособление деепричастного оборота двумя тире. Да, необычно, но именно это пунктуационное решение мне кажется основным. И тогда запятая перед вторым тире вроде бы и не нужна.
Чужие книги я листал за томом том;
Быть может, я мечтал: какой-нибудь поэт
Мне — песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
Спаленный солнцем мозг — подскажет путь... Но нет!

Спасибо, Римма, почти рядом. // Вы и оригинал прочитали!  Просто класс! // Я тут решила: вот сейчас переведу стих, чем я хуже других. Но в первой же строфе так запуталась с грамматикой, что до перевода дело не дошло) Раньше у них порядок слов был довольно свободный, почти как у нас.  Ну и дальше читать не стала. // А к вам еще один вопрос: а можно МНЕ оставить, не менять на МОЙ? Уж очень далеко определение от существительного.  Ну и запятая перед вторым тире нужна ли?

Не, Sharon, собственный полный перевод я никак не потяну. А Вы все-таки верните свой ответ о Мандельштаме. (Уже ж я и просила, и проголосовала за восстановление.)

Я не видела, Римма, извините, сейчас верну.  А вам до победы остался маленький шажок,  я была уверена, что вы догадаетесь.

Чужие книги я листал за томом том...
«Быть может, — я мечтал, — какой-нибудь поэт,
Мне песнями кропя как благостным дождём
Спалённый солнцем мозг, подскажет путь». Но нет!
(Оформил прямую речь, в основном для обозначения её конца, и убрал запятые внутри деепричастного оборота, сравнение назвав качеством).

Комментарий к ответу
Спасибо за интерес к теме, голос от меня.

Постановка многоточия (вместо двоеточия) предоставляется разумным решением, так как мы выделяем первую часть в отдельное предложение.

Возражаю против обособления тире: я мечтал — это обычное вводное предложение. К тому же нежелательно зря тратить этот знак) Соответственно, классическое оформление прямой речи тоже не выглядит обоснованным.

Мы остаемся наедине с простым предложением, осложненным деепричастным и сравнительным оборотами. Надо указать грамматическую основу. Рискну предположить, что это поэт подскажет.  Мне — дополнение?

Со сравнительным оборотом как благостным дождём можно особо не церемониться: его можно обособлять или нет.

А вот с деепричастным оборотом сложнее — здесь как раз основное решение. В принципе необособление деепричастного оборота возможно, но здесь вряд ли: оборот значительно распространен. Нужно указать его границы и обозначить на письме.

Или нужно вообще как-то перестраивать предложение.


Добавлю, что перевод сонета мне нравится, и даже очень. Русская речь легкая, изящная, передающая все оттенки чувств. Стих кажется почти игривым, автор будто немного рисуется. Но есть ли это в английском оригинале? Фразеология и грамматика значительно изменены, хотя смысл, безусловно, верный.
А если грамматику немного подкорректировать для ясности, переводчик, наверное, не обидится) Хотелось бы, чтобы чтение приносило удовольствие, а структура предложения понималась бы сразу.

Я даю свой ответ:
         Чужие книги я листал за томом том:
         Быть может, я мечтал, какой-нибудь поэт —
         Мне песнями кропя, как благостным дождем,
         Спаленный солнцем мозг — подскажет путь... Но нет!

Авторский  вариант верен, можно только использовать тире вместо запятых для обозначения границ деепричастного оборота.
Так мы исключаем неоднозначность прочтения, что является стилистической погрешностью. Обособление деепричастного оборота тире обычно не применяется, но здесь такой вариант кажется обоснованным. Все-таки ясность текста — это главное для знаков пунктуации.
Грамматический казус в том, что дополнение МНЕ может относиться как к сказуемому, так и к деепричастию: (1) поэт подскажет мне...  (2) мне кропя мозг...
Верен вариант (2), что следует из источника: там мой мозг кропя, как мне подсказали в ответах.
Хотелось бы услышать вашу оценку и вообще мнение о результатах конкурса.
